# How to add an existing JInternalFrame to my Netbeans project?

Tags: swing, netbeans-8

Since "initComponents" methods and settings fixed, I can't find how to add an existing JInternalFrame to my Netbeans project. Can someone point me in the right directions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two thing:

1 - copy the files of the jInternalFrame that you want to add to the folder of the project.

2 - drag from the file explorer that you use directly to your project tab in netbeans.

In both approaches you have to be careful to copy both the .java and the .form files.